# Can I design an android app using shell script?

Tags: shell-script, android

Is there a way to design android app using shell script? If so how?

Comment: You mean instead of with an editor? `echo first code line > application_source`, `echo second code line >> application_source`

Comment: no no usually we write shell scripts for Linux desktops, but can i design an android app using shell script??not editor, the language??

Comment: AFAIK you can run bash under android, but I don't know of any commandline like interfacing to the graphics surface. For Linux desktop such tools are heavily restricted as well (menu selection, yes/no answer boxes), as there is no call-back mechanism that is used in complete application frameworks)

Comment: mmm :( so what should i learn to develop android app? java???

Comment: Yeah, Java! see [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) for an introduction to the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Consult the Android developer site.

[Get Started with Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/develop/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

No way .

you have to use Java or any programming Languages to write Android Apps .